# Django 2.0 Static Files not recognized in Apache2

Tags: python, django, apache, static

My website is online, but it can't find the static files ;/
The configurations seem to be all ok, can't find the error...

I don't have admin permission on the server, so it kind'a sucks..
but, at least they pass me the configurations they've put..

Apache Configuration:

```
<VirtualHost *>
        ServerAdmin suporte@pop-rs.rnp.br
        DocumentRoot /home/metis/public_html/
        ServerName agata.pgie.ufrgs.br
        ServerAlias www.agata.pgie.ufrgs.br
        #ErrorLog /var/log/apache2/agata-error.log
        #CustomLog /var/log/apache2/agata-access.log common

        <Directory /home/metis/public_html/static>
               Require all granted
        </Directory>

        <Directory /home/metis/public_html/AGATA/textMiningProject>
               <Files wsgi.py>
                       Require all granted
               </Files>
        </Directory>

        WSGIDaemonProcess agata python-path=/home/metis/public_html/AGATA python-home=/home/metis/public_html/AGATA/agataenv
        WSGIProcessGroup agata
        WSGIScriptAlias / /home/metis/public_html/AGATA/textMiningProject/wsgi.py
</VirtualHost>
```

Django Version: 2.0
settings.py

## Static files (CSS, JavaScript, Images)

## https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/howto/static-files/

```
STATIC_PATH = os.path.join(BASE_DIR,'static')

STATIC_URL = '/static/' # You may find this is already defined as such.

STATIC_ROOT = '/home/metis/public_html/static'

STATICFILES_DIRS = [
    STATIC_PATH
]

MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'media')

MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
```

And it was asked to the admins to insert the following, no changes in the result tho..

```
    Alias /media/ /home/metis/public_html/AGATA/media
Alias /static/ /home/metis/public_html/static

<Directory /home/metis/public_html/static>

…

    Order allow,deny
    Allow from all
</Directory>
```

can someone help?

Edit 1:
The output for **collecstatic**:

> 0 static files copied to '/home/metis/public_html/static', 166
>   unmodified.

The error on the site:

> simple-sidebar.css Failed to load resource: the server responded with
>   a status of 404 (Not Found)

Comment: Did you run `collectstatic`?

Comment: yes, but doesn't work still..

Comment: What is the output of `collectstatic` and what happens when you try to hit one of the static files... is it a 404 response code?

Comment: @MrName, edited the post with the outputs